# I can use SocketHttpHandler instead of HttpMessageHandler?

Tags: flurl

Flurl is configured by default to use **HttpMessageHandler**. However, my application uses .NET Core 3.1 and I know that this framework has better support for the new **SocketHttpHandler** class.
So can I create a custom class like this?

```
public class CustomHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    #region Overrides of DefaultHttpClientFactory

    /// <summary>
    ///     Override in custom factory to customize the creation of HttpClientHandler used in all Flurl HTTP calls.
    ///     In order not to lose Flurl.Http functionality, it is recommended to call base.CreateMessageHandler and
    ///     customize the result.
    /// </summary>
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() => new SocketsHttpHandler
    {
        AllowAutoRedirect           = false,
        ConnectTimeout              = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        PooledConnectionLifetime    = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        PooledConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        MaxConnectionsPerServer     = 20,
        SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AllowRenegotiation                  = false,
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true
        }
    };

    #endregion
}
```

And configuration in **OnStartup**

```
FlurlHttp.ConfigureClient(AppConstants.ServiceUrl, cli =>
                {
                    cli.BaseUrl = AppConstants.ServiceUrl;

                    cli.Configure(settings =>
                    {
                        settings.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                        settings.Timeout                = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                        settings.HttpClientFactory      = new CustomHttpClientFactory();
                    }).WithHeaders(headers);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpMessageHandler` is an abstract class. The implementation used by Flurl by default is `HttpClientHandler`. I'm guessing that's what you want to swap out for `SocketsHttpHandler`.

Fortunately, the .NET team prefers the latter implementation as well, which is why [`HttpClientHandler` now delegates literally all of its work to `SocketsHttpHandler`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.cs).

In other words, if you're on a platform that supports `SocketsHttpHandler` (.NET Core 2.1 or greater), you're using it by default. No custom factory is necessary.

That said, if you need to initialize the handler with some custom configuration, then I think what you've done is fine.